# TeamCity trigger a build after a succesfull build on a generic branch name

Tags: teamcity

I have a TeamCity project :

- Commit build
- Another build

I want that if my commit build is successful on a generic branch name (if the branch name contains a specific word), another build start. The specific word is `toto-ok` in the example.

Example:

- commit build on `develop`: do nothing more
- commit build on branch feature/blabla-**toto-ok**-blabla: **trigger
  the other build**
- commit build on branch `feature/something-else`: do nothing more
- commit build on branch feature/something-**toto-ok**-else:
  **trigger the other build**